# Pandas "read_sql" UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, database, pandas, vertica

I use `pandas` to read from Vertica DataBase:

`pd.read_sql(query, self._conn)`

But it fails with

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 1: invalid continuation byte`.

Other queries don't fail, so the **problem** is in some specific column from this query.

I need all data - what should i do? I can make changes in Vertica too, but i can't change the table values...

P.S. This is how i create a connection for Vertica:

```
conn_info = url2vertica(url)
conn_info["read_timeout"] = 2400
conn_info["ssl"] = False
vrt = vertica_python.connect(**conn_info)
```

Comment: I think you need to pass some encoding paramenters to you `connect` function.  Like `charset='utf8'` or something like that.  I think it needs to match whatever the encoding of your database is, because aparently it is not 'utf-8'.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind, Yes, the first thing i tried to do - to explictly set "utf-16", somewhere, but `read_sql` doesn't have an interface for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, i came to this solution: using `isUTF8()` in the  sql-query.

Also in [here](https://github.com/uber/vertica-python/blob/5b31d3f57f00e81eb18cd5487b1e56aa1eeb15ae/README.md), in **UTF-8 encoding issues**, it's shown, that we can ignore errors via `'unicode_error': 'ignore'`.

Comment: The problem comes from the encoding of your connection object which does not seem to support utf8. The 0xe9 refers to the "é" letter... There should be a better solution to solve this issue by enabling utf8 support. Not too sure how though